# CssBaseline Overriding theme background colour MUI? Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui to make a theme which works fine but when I add `<CssBaseline/>` to the App.js it turns the background colour white even though I put in the index.css that the background colour should be #1f262a. I tried adding:

```
  overrides: {
    CssBaseline: {
      "@global": {
        body: {
          backgroundColor: "#1f262a",
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

To the theme but it did not make a difference. I appreciate any responses.

Comment: Which version of material ui do you use? v4 or v5?

Answer (score 0):

you should use MuiCssBaseline instead CssBaseline:

```
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      "@global": {
        body: {
          backgroundColor: "#1f262a",
        }
      }
    }
  }
```